# Publish ASP.NET Core app to Azure not working

Tags: sql, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am literally following the steps here line by line:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1

But I keep getting this error when trying to publish the app:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Web deployment task failed. ((4/10/2020 10:26:03 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)

(4/10/2020 10:26:03 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
The database 'WebApplication1_db' could not be created. WebApplication1     0
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction? What does this error mean? Is it an issue with the code? Azure? How do I start trying to diagnose the issue? What tests can I run? I've spent ages on this and can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like "The database 'WebApplication1_db' could not be created". The "cloud like" way would be to use managed sql databases from azure in production. That means: Create a database in azure portal. Set configuration string in your app to point to this database. S.a. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/

Comment: This tutorial may help too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase

Comment: I have tried creating a DB in the Azure portal, and then set the connection string in `appsettings.json`. But that doesn’t handle any of the migration etc. it just publishes the site and then fails to load since the database is uninitialised. Thanks for the tip tho!

Comment: Of course it's not initialized. In general you have the option to do it manually (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) or using the migration feature of the framework you're using. E.g. for EF core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli - for a first test you could simply export your local db and import it on Azure using SSMS.

Comment: I guess I’m not really used to using external tools to setup configurations etc (new to databases). I managed to get it to work using your suggestion of SSMS.

Comment: Did the issue resolved for you? If so, Would you like to post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?

Comment: @HarryStuart Whether your problem is solved ？ I think  Monika's comment should be effective for you.

Comment: It is, but their is no answer to select.

Comment: According to the official documentation, our operation is no problem. It is recommended to choose another region to create a webapp and follow the official documentation step by step.

Comment: I have also encountered special characters in the webapp name before, causing many unknown errors. It is recommended to use English names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation, the following are my steps. The official documentation and deployment steps are normal. If you still have any doubts, it is recommended to reinstall VS2019 or replace the pc and try again, which may be due to the computer environment.

**The steps are as follows:**

Step 1.

[image]

Step 2.

[image]

Step 3.

[image]

Step 4.

[image]

Step 5.

[image]

Step 6.

[image]

Step 7.

[image]